# how to use Custom post type dynamically

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a new template page and I am displaying custom post type in that page as follows,

```
                   <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <?php $i = 1 ?>
                    <?php $posts = get_posts(array(
                        'post_type' => 'astroalbums',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1
                        ));
                        foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
                    <?php if ($i == 1): ?>
                    <?php $link = get_permalink($post->ID); ?>
                    <?php the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>' );?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($i == 3){$i = 1;} else {$i++;} ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

My custom post type is "astroalbums" and I want to use it dynamically. I have 4 custom post types. I want to create new page in dashboard and assign the above page template i have created. and each page will call different custom post type.
It will be really great help 
Thank you,
Trupti

Answer (score 0):

You're retrieving the posts correctly, but it's seems that the problem is inside the `foreach` loop. As the default WordPress loop is not being used, you need to call functions which receive the post id as parameter or use the properties present in the `$post` object (which is an instance of the `WP_POST` class) in order to display the data.

One possible solution:

```
<?php
    $posts = get_posts([
        'post_type' => 'astroalbums',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    ]);
?>

<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): ?>
    <?php $link = get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>

    <h3 class="entry-title">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID ); ?>
        </a>
    </h3>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```